# Concatenate 2 csv files using panda and not include row index

Tags: python, pandas, csv

How do I concatenate 2 CSV files using panda such that the resulting CSV file doesn't have row indexes? See example below:

file1.csv

```
date                    type      price           amount    
2017-09-02 00:00:01     b         0.279111        94000       
2017-09-02 00:00:01     b         0.279           43800          
2017-09-02 00:00:01     b         0.2789          6000     
2017-09-02 00:00:01     b         0.278812        2000         
2017-09-02 00:00:01     b         0.278           7250
```

file2.csv

```
date                    type    price           amount    
2018-03-02 00:00:01     q         0.279111       1400       
2018-05-01 00:00:01     q         0.279          3800          
2017-09-02 00:00:01     q         0.2789         640
```

desired_file.csv

```
date                   type       price           amount    
2017-09-02 00:00:01     b         0.279111        94000       
2017-09-02 00:00:01     b         0.279           43800          
2017-09-02 00:00:01     b         0.2789          6000     
2017-09-02 00:00:01     b         0.278812        2000         
2017-09-02 00:00:01     b         0.278           7250     
2018-03-02 00:00:01     q         0.279111        1400       
2018-05-01 00:00:01     q         0.279           3800          
2017-09-02 00:00:01     q         0.2789          640
```

NOT THIS:

```
     date                   type       price           amount    
1    2017-09-02 00:00:01     b         0.279111        94000       
2    2017-09-02 00:00:01     b         0.279           43800          
3    2017-09-02 00:00:01     b         0.2789          6000     
4    2017-09-02 00:00:01     b         0.278812        2000         
5    2017-09-02 00:00:01     b         0.278           7250     
6    2018-03-02 00:00:01     q         0.279111        1400       
7    2018-05-01 00:00:01     q         0.279           3800          
8    2017-09-02 00:00:01     q         0.2789          640
```

My code:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.read_csv("file1.csv")
b = pd.read_csv("file2.csv")

combined = pd.concat([a, b])

combined.to_csv("desired_file.csv")
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Add `index=False`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the [`docs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

```
combined.to_csv("desired_file.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks :)